# Let $\int_Xf\,d\mu,\int_Xg\,d\mu$ be finite, must $\int_X fg\, d\mu$ be finite

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\scr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f,g:(X,\scr{M},\mu)\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ be measurable with finite integrals over $X$. Must $\int_X fg \,d\mu$ be finite ?

My guess is yes, I already tried proving it for sometime. I want to see if there is a counterexample . If there aren't any please inform me that the fact is true without saying a proof and I will try to prove it again, as I think it should be easy to prove if it's true.

Thank you

---

The question is equivalent to asking if $\int_X f^2\,d\mu$ must be finite. One of the directions is trivial, for the other direction just note that 
$$\int_Xfg\,d\mu=\frac{1}{2}[\int_X(f+g)^2\,d\mu-\int_Xf^2\,d\mu-\int_Xg^2\,d\mu]$$

---

The question can also be asked as : Is $L^1(\mu)$ a ring under pointwise multiplication and addition ?

Comment: @n.c. it doesn't help here, does it ? because it bounds the integral of fg be the square root of the integrals of the SQUARE of f and the integral of the SQUARE  of g, which we still don't know if they are finite or not

Comment: How about $f(x)=g(x)=x^{-1/2}$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: @RahulNarain OK :). I am glad I asked this question, before spending more time on it.

Comment: @RahulNarain Why don't you put your comment as an answer ? If you don't put it , I will just delete the question. But this is a loss. If someone else wants to ask the same question,S/he would see that question instead of asking it again

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer is emphatically *no*: One standard counterexample is

$$f(x) = x^{-1/2} \chi_{(0,1]} = g(x)$$

Morally, we shouldn't expect this to be true. The $L^1$ norm does a better job at controlling broadness instead of spikiness, and the $L^2$ norm is much more sensitive to spikes. This is because squaring a function will simply emphasize the spikes, as $t^2 > t$ for $t > 1$. So whenever $f$ and $g$ are (integrable) functions whose peaks align well, it's possible that their pointwise product is so large that it's not integrable.

This is a rather nice general theme: The larger $p$ is, the better job $L^p$ is at controlling spikiness, and the smaller $p$ is, the better it is at controlling broadness.

If we require that $f$ and $g$ are square-integrable too (which puts a much larger restriction on how spiky they can be), then Holder's inequality does imply that their product is integrable.